# Xamarin Live Player does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Using VS 2017 community 15.3 preview 5

Xamarin Preview is up to date and xamarin for visual studio is included , xamarin updater is installed but the xamarin live player button is not showing up .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BETA RELEASE: 15.3 PREVIEW 5 does not include the Xamarin Live Player:

> Note that this Beta version is a smaller release compared to the current Alpha preview. In particular, it does not include the Xamarin Live Player, Docker, Azure Functions, or Xamarin IoT preview features announced at Build. Please stay on the Alpha channel if you wish to continue to preview those features.

Re: https://releases.xamarin.com/beta-release-15-3-preview-5/

Comment: Can i Change the Channel from BETA to Alpha or Should i uninstall The Beta Version?

Comment: There is an issue with the current version that prevents Live Player from being available. See James Montemagnos update here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100103/important-visual-studio-2017-15-3-preview-users-please-read-if-new

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with a similar issue, I found that Xamarin Live Player is not enabled by default you need to do this  yourself:
Go to Tools> Options> Xamarin > Other > Enable Xamarin Live Player.

Comment: I can't see "other" option

Comment: @Ali Update your visual studio 2017 preview.

Comment: I already have VS 2007 professional, is preview version latest than no preview version? this is what I have. Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.3.3
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.3+26730.12

Comment: @Ali To Run live player you need to install VS 2017 PREVIEW (latest version)

Answer (score 0):

There’s problems with the versions of Visual Studio. Now you first need to install the TestFlight app from apple and then from inside of  it you download the newest version of Xamarin live player. I leave you the link where you can find it.

https://fastring.xamarinliveplayer.com/